# ASP.net MVC 5 Integration with OWIN same as Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

For Web API integration we use following thing in asp.net mvc 5 template onwards.

```
app.UserWebAPI(configuration);
```

Here we plug web api into Owin pipe line.

Is that same thing possible for MVC . Something like

```
app.UseMvc();
```

Also does Owin and Mvc use same routetable for url configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you cannot host mvc app with owin since mvc has dependency on system.web namespace which restrict self hosting .

But you can use FubuMVC, Nancy and Simple.Web etc

Comment: Or use the preview of the next asp.net version which fixes that - and integrates webapi into mvc.

Comment: Are you talking about VS 2015 Preview ? I have tried that and it is working. Actually it is completly new development.